# How to enable CORS for asp.net mvc web site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cors

I want to enable CORS for an action in my asp.net mvc 4 web site.
This is possible for web api
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api
Is there a similar solution for mvc web site?
I also want to be able to restrict this for origin web sites I want.
Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what you mean by being able to restrict for origin web sites.

Comment: [I just answered a similar question, hope this helps][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084594/how-to-enable-cors-js-mvc-web-api/31138593#31138593

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to create your Custom authorization Like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Referrer Url Custom Authorize
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ReferrerUrlAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        IList<string> webSitesAllowed = new List<string>() { "http://mywebsite.com", "http://customersite.com" };
        string urlReferrer = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;

        //checking if the referrer url exists in your list of sites allowed
        if (!webSitesAllowed.Contains(urlReferrer))
            return false;  //access denied
        return true;
    }
}
```

and in your controller class must be set the ReferrerUrlAuthorize

```
   [ReferrerUrlAuthorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }
}
```