# How to enable CORS (JS + MVC Web API)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, cors

On my client side I have this code:

```
<script>
    function SignIn() {
        $.ajax({

            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:54976/api/values?email=dieter&password=borgers',
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            },
            //data: parameters,
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },

            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },

            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },

            error: function () {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And then on my 'local server' side I have this:

```
public string Get(string Email, string Password)
        {
            Request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            return Email + " : " + Password;
        }
```

And this in my web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

What am I doing wrong?
I always het this error: Reading from external source not allowed. This can be helped by enabling CORS.

Comment: I think you also need dataType: "jsonp"

Comment: Have you tried to use the Cors attribute on your controllers? `[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]`?

Comment: Both still give me back a failure.

Comment: Which version of Web Api are you using?

Comment: ID: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi

Comment: Version: 4.0.30506.0

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue before and here is what I came up with.

I created a custom action attribute

```
public class AllowCrossDomain : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//Note "*" will allow all - you can change this to only allow tursted domains
    }
}
```

Now add the attribute to your action 
This adds the header in so the client does not need to worry about it.  I was having an issue using jsonp  (which allows cors) and needed so specify my datatype as json

```
[AllowCrossDomain]
public string Get(string Email, string Password)
    {
        Request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        return Email + " : " + Password;
    }
```